# Order of accessing and Initializing Static Fields Java

Tags: java, constructor, static

Consider the following example:

```
class Super{ 
   static String ID = "1234";
}
class Sub extends Super{
  static{ System.out.println("In Sub");
}

public static void main(String ...args){
  System.out.println(Sub.ID);
}
```

The way I understand this: if this was new Sub() in main, it would call super() constructor of Super class, obviously first executing static initializers if any then static initializers in Sub, then non-static init blocks and constructors in this particular order.

Having said this, this program prints "1234", How so if Sub doesn't inherit static fields, Shouldn't this be a compile error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're allowed to access (accessible) `static` members of a type through an expression of a subtype of that type. At compile time, it is resolved as an access through the declaring type, `Super` in this case.

Comment: Sorry, it's confusing a bit to me, How is this different from inheriting the static field, knowing that static fields can't be inherited.

Comment: @user1529412 If it was inherited, the `Sub` class would have its own copy of the field (or member). In this case it doesn't.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis inheritance doesn't copy fields or methods (or anything).

Comment: But Since I am able to do Sub.ID = "abc", it means I am able to change the value through Sub, I know it is not inherited per what you said "Only allowing access", but the behavior is that of inheritance, and yes I know static belongs to class. I would have thought Sub.ID should not allow access as ID belongs to "Super" class.

Comment: @user1529412 It's an allowance that the Java language makes. When you do `Sub.ID`, the compiler actually sees `Super.ID`.